# Strongly Named assembly validation failed, referenced from non signed project

Tags: c#, sign

after one hour googling, I can't find the right answer to the issue I'm experiencing, hope you can help me.

I have a C# framework 3.5 class library project, so I signed it creating a simple key (NOT delayed signin) and then I obsfuscated the DLL.

Then I'm trying to access that assembly from a Windows form application, but when I make some call to any method of the assembly I get the error: **"Strong Name Validation Failed"**.

I don't know if I should sign the Windows application too to refer to the strongly named assembly, or add some sort of special tag at the using directives in the source code of the Windows application.

I'm new working with strong names, so please give me some advice in how to deal with this. I need to strongly name the assembly in order to guarantee that no intruder could replace my version of the assembly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for taking away your time, I found the reason for my issue and the solution for it:

First of all, when I obsfuscated the assembly, the generated SNK didn't worked anymore, so the solution is to re-generate the SNK after obsfuscating the assembly.

Second, I needed to include the SNK file on my Windows Application in order to validate the strongly named assembly.

With both changes, everything worked fine for me.

Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: That explains. Signing the assembly makes .Net check if the file has been tampered with. An obfuscator changes the file and therefore .Net sees it has been tampered with. You do not need to sign any applications who will use the assembly. A signed assembly can only reference other signed assemblies.